# Join decimal part

Tags: number-representation

I have a list of mesures that each vector is like `{0,1,-2,259}` but it should be like `{0.1,-2.259}` So I did a rule, like `list/. {a_,b_,c_,d_}->{a.b,c.d}` but for the positives number it works fine! but for vector like this one I get `{0.1,(-2).239}` how can I fix this?

Comment: No, is like i put it

Comment: I exported the data from Matlab as csv, but my decimal symbol here is a , so...

Comment: Sounds like you are after a kludge solution to a problem that ought to be fixed on the matlab side.

Comment: Please note that the `.` in your rule is shorthand for `Dot` and not a decimal point!  You almost certainly don't want the inner product of the whole part and fractional part!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May be I'm overthinking this one.

```
list = {0, 1, -2, 259};
f[x_, y_] :=  x + (2 Boole@NonNegative[x] - 1 ) y/10^IntegerLength[y]//N ;
list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} -> {f[a, b], f[c, d]}

(* {0.1, -2.259} *)
```

Comment: just beat me to it, yours is the same as mine (essentially):`toDecimal[a_, b_] := N[a + (-1)^Sign[a] b 10^(-IntegerLength[b])]`;

`list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {toDecimal[a, b], toDecimal[c, d]}`

(* {0.1, -2.259} *)

Comment: @chuy Yup. `(-1)^Sign[a]` in definitively nicer.

Comment: Thanks, this work, but can't understand how...it will take me more than an hour to understand it :)

Comment: @Kafkarudo Take the code in the comment above by chuy. It does the same thing and I believe it's easier to understand

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Alan's answer but a bit more direct:

```
fix = ToExpression @ ToString @ Row[#, "."] &;

in = {0, 1, -2, 259};

fix /@ Partition[in, 2]
```

> ```
> {0.1, -2.259}
> ```

Comment: Why not `Row[#,"."]&/@Partition[in,2]` ?

Comment: @Kafkarudo I assumed that you wanted numeric values as output rather than merely expressions that *look like* numeric values.  If not then yes, you may drop `ToString` and `ToExpression`.

Answer (score 3):

The first output may look ok but it's not actually a number.   See if this does what you want:

```
test = {0, 1, -2, 259}
combine[{a_, b_}] := ToExpression[ToString[StringForm["``.``", a, b]]]
Map[combine, ArrayReshape[test, {Length[test]/2, 2}]]
```

Comment: similarly: `ToExpression[StringJoin[Riffle[ ToString /@ #, "."]]] & /@ 
 Partition[{0, 1, -2, 259}, 2] `

Answer (score 1):

```
ClearAll[f];
f = With[{left = FromDigits /@ IntegerDigits /@ #[[;; ;; 2]],
          right = N /@ FromDigits /@ ({#, 0} & /@ IntegerDigits /@ #[[2 ;; ;; 2]]),
          sign = Sign /@ #[[;; ;; 2]] /. 0 -> 1}, sign (left + right)] &;

list = {0, 1, -2, 259};
list2 = {0, 1, -2, 259, 3, 141592653};

Grid[{#, f@#} & /@ {list, list2} , Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
f = With[{p = Length[IntegerDigits@#2]}, 
    N[#1 + (2 UnitStep[#1] - 1) #2 10^(-p)]] &;
g = f @@@ Partition[#, 2] &;
```

Test case:

```
test = {{0, 1, -2, 259}, {-1, 2, 3, 124}, {-2, 34, -3, 45}, {1, 0, 3, 
   4}}
Grid[{#, "\[RightArrow]", g@#} & /@ test]
```

[image]

Now strings  would be required to deal with e.g.

```
test2 = {{"-1", "04", "0", "04"}, {"-1", "234", "2", "32"}, {"0", 
    "2345", "2", "003"}};
```

In this case:

```
h[u_] := N[
     ToExpression[{#1, #2}].{1, (2 UnitStep[ToExpression@#1] - 
          1) 10^-StringLength[#2]}] & @@@ Partition[u, 2];
```

So,

```
Grid[{#, "\[RightArrow]", h@#} & /@ test2]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
list = {0, 1, -2, 259};
list /. {a_, b_, c_, d_} :> {a.b, If[Sign[c] == -1, -(-c).d, c.d]}
(*{0.1, -2.259}*)

ToExpression[
 StringReplace[
  ToString /@ 
   Partition[{0, 1, -2, 259}, 2], {{"{" | "}" | (Whitespace )} :> "", 
   "," -> "."}]]

(*{0.1, -2.259}*)
```

Comment: I am not the one who down-voted, but I see why: this does not work.  Look at the `FullForm` -- you have `Dot` in the result, not a Real number.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I know. I have looked at it previously after some one down-voted. thanks.